# Error making listNotebooks request using Evernote's Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, cordova, thrift, evernote

I am creating a Cordova/Phonegap mobile app using the Ionic framework. I'm using Evernote's Javascript SDK and successfully got the OAuth process working.

I'm stuck at the very last step. I am trying to list my notebooks and keep generating an error. Everything seems to be working fine up until this point:

```
noteStore.listNotebooks(authTokenEvernote, function (notebooks)
```

At that point, I get an error that reads "{"position":0,"totalSize":0}". I've looked all over the forum and can't figure out what it means, or how to fix it.

Here is my code.

```
// authTokenEvernote can now be used to send request to the Evernote Cloud API
console.log('got access token:', authTokenEvernote)
console.log('got notestore url:', noteStoreURL)

// Here, we connect to the Evernote Cloud API and get a list of all of the
// notebooks in the authenticated user's account:

var noteStoreTransport = new Thrift.BinaryHttpTransport("noteStoreURL");
var noteStoreProtocol = new Thrift.BinaryProtocol(noteStoreTransport);
var noteStore = new NoteStoreClient(noteStoreProtocol);

noteStore.listNotebooks(authTokenEvernote, function (notebooks) {
                console.log('success!! : ');
                console.log(notebooks);

}, function onerror(error) {
                console.log('error:')
                console.log(error);        
});        

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `listNotebooks` method (like most Evernote methods) returns a `err` object first, then the object containing the notebooks.

Here is an example of how the `listNotebooks` method could be called:

```
var notebooks = noteStore.listNotebooks(function(err, notebooks) {
  console.log("Found " + notebooks.length + " notebooks:");
  for (var i in notebooks) {
    console.log("  * " + notebooks[i].name);
  }
  console.log(notebooks)

});
```